# HDMI to USB-C doesn't work

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi

Recently I bought an adapter to connect my USB devices and HDMI via USB-C to my laptop (with Thunderbolt). In Windows, HDMI works correctly and I can use the display normally via the adapter, but in Ubuntu I cannot make another display appear when connected via this adapter.

Is there any solution to this? I should say that if I connected the display via HDMI from the laptop then it works normally, so the issue seems to be between Ubuntu and USB-C.

Comment: Solved. I forgot to firstly update drivers for my graphic card and that was reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: To fix it we need to install our GPU drivers. I have NVIDIA GPU but I think it will be working also with Radeon. Go to Terminal -> "ubuntu-drivers devices" -> one of the drivers should be mark as "distro non-free recommended" so choose this one with "sudo apt install <driver_name>" and then "sudo reboot". Complete

Answer (score 1):

To fix it install the GPU drivers. Open the terminal and run `ubuntu-drivers devices` -> one of the drivers should be marked as `distro non-free recommended` so choose this one with `sudo apt install <driver_name> && sudo reboot`

Alternatively automatically install the recommended proprietary graphics drivers with `sudo ubuntu-drivers install && sudo reboot`